# Perplexities about TLS handshake

Tags: tls

I analyzed the TLS (1.2) handshake and I didn't manage to understand the message after the `Change Chipher Spec`

Here it is:

[image]

It is called "Encrypted Handshake Message" by Wireshark and it is sent by the server to the client and vice-versa. What is the content of this message? It should be the `Finished` message but what is its specific content? I also noticed that the length is different for every different ciphersuite, so, is this length specified somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Change Cipher Spec` message means: from now on, records will be encrypted with the newly negotiated cipher suite and keys. So all subsequent records *will* be encrypted, and that's what you observe: an encrypted record. Of course you cannot see the contents: that's the point of encryption.

Right after the `Change Cipher Spec` follows a `Finished` message, which serves as confirmation that the handshake worked properly. The raw contents have length 12 bytes, and are computed as a sort-of hash of all previous handshake messages. These 12 bytes will be encrypted, which entails adding the record MAC value, then possibly some padding (if using a block cipher in CBC mode).

For instance, if, in your example, you used a cipher suite with 3DES in CBC mode as block cipher, and SHA-1 for integrity, then 20 bytes are appended for the MAC, then between 1 and 8 bytes for padding, so that the total length is a multiple of 8 (3DES uses blocks of 8 bytes). This yields 40 bytes, and that's precisely what you observe.

See [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), in particular [section 7.4.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.9) for the `Finished` message; see also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/20847#20847) for a walk-through of SSL/TLS.